# Duplicate messages on Azure Web API

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am working on web application that has angular 4 on frontend and WEB API on backend. This application is hosted on MS Azure and until now we didn't have any issues.

Currently we need to integrate with one payment provider. During payment user is redirected to his payment page, and if everything goes well user is redirected back to our web site. Beside the browser redirect (which may fail) payment provider supports server to server call (HTTP GET). In this way they make sure we get information about the transaction. The problem here is that instead of one call to our Web API backend we get always two calls. After checking the request origin IP addresses I concluded that there is two origins (one is payment provider address and another is IP located in USA, which I assume belongs to MS). This looks to me like a routing problem, but I am not very experienced at this.

Did anybody have similar problem on Azure while hosting web application ?

Answer (score 0):

According to your decription, it seems that fails for [cross domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) request. Azure website is supposed to manage CORS for you.

I think you missed a handy Azure website blade: Specify the origins that should be allowed to make cross-origin calls (for example: http://example.com:12345). To allow all, use "*" and remove all other origins from the list. Slashes are not allowed as part of domain or after TLD.

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) allows JavaScript code running in a browser on an external host to interact with your backend. Specify the origins that should be allowed to make cross-origin calls (for example: http://example.com:12345). To allow all, use "*" and remove all other origins from the list. Slashes are not allowed as part of domain or after TLD.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tom. After some discussion with the Payment provider support, we concluded that the the same IP address was reported by some other clients as well. They have it on a blacklist. After we enabled HTTPS we didn't get any duplicated message. We totally neglected this since we were testing with the test account. I think CORS should not be the issue in this case, because we are having direct server to server call.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If it is server to server call, it has no relationship with CORS. If it is solved on your side. You could add an answer to help more communities who have the same issue easily to search.